# How to drag/drop from Intranet Web site to local OS?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, desktop

I am trying to customize an Asset Management website.  The links we have it storing are actually paths to files on our local network.  We want to be able to drag these links into locally running applications and have them behave as if the drag/drop was initiated from a file explorer.  (Most important is dragging a link to an image file into Photoshop, but a more general purpose solution would be welcomed).

I have looked into the HTML 5 dataTransfer.setData() method, but I am unsure what MIME type to set.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png" 
    draggable="true" 
    ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'R:/ELEMLIB/stills/city/143_4361.JPG');" 
    onclick="return false"
>
Drag me
</a>
```

Windows 7, Chrome and/or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try `text/uri-list`, [Mozilla recommends it for links](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#link).  You may need to write the paths in URI format, eg. `file:///R/ELEMLIB/stills/city/143_4361.JPG`.